# Bash Shell Script: How can I restrict getopts so that it only takes one type of option?

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I am using getopts and for the options I want to accept just one type of letter but it can be passed multiple times. Can't figure out how to do this but it should work the way `ls -l` does where that `ls -lllllll` and `ls -l -l -l -l -l` all return the same thing and it only runs once.

```
while getopts ":abc" opt; do
        case "$opt" in
                a) echo "a"
                ;;
                b) echo "b"
                ;;
                p) echo "c"
                ;;
                ?) echo "error"
                ;;
        esac
done
```

so in this example, I want `./program.sh -a`, `./program.sh -aaaaaaa` (with any number of as), and `./program.sh -a -a -a -a` to all return "a" just one time and then something like `./program.sh -ab` or `./program.sh -abc` or `./program.sh -a -c` to return an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't take action while parsing your options. Just record which options are seen, and take action afterwards.

```
while getopts ":abc" opt; do
        case "$opt" in
                a) A=1
                ;;
                b) B=1
                ;;
                c) C=1
                ;;
                ?) echo "error"
                ;;
        esac
done

if ((A + B + C > 1)); then
    printf 'Only one of -a, -b, -c should be used.\n' >&2
    exit 1;
fi

[[ $A == 1 ]] && echo "a"
[[ $B == 1 ]] && echo "b"
[[ $C == 1 ]] && echo "c"
```

Comment: Also referred opt parameters different.

Comment: @konsolebox I'm not sure what you mean, though it made me take a closer look at the question and realize I missed the desire to raise an error if multiple different options are used.

Comment: OP's example uses two option variables: option and opt, which probably doesn't matter to him/her. I was giving a co heads up.

Comment: Oh, my eyes slid right over that. Thanks.

Comment: @konsolebox thanks for catching! didn't update from when I changed this example from my actual code —just edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the logic yourself to handle multiple invocations of the same argument.

```
A=0
while getopts ":a" option; do
        case "$option" in
                a) [[ $A != 1 ]] && echo "a" 
                   A=1
                ;;
                *) echo "error"
                ;;
        esac
done
```